# CSS Link Transition Issue

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want my link to have a smooth transition no matter how fast I move my cursor over it. And the problem is demonstrated in this plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/UPEdxjWIT4y12RbqRo9a?p=info

Here is the problem: if I hover over the link slowly, it works fine. However, if you move your cursor quickly to the link, the smooth transition is gone and the link just gets to the position directly. How do I get the smooth transition when I move my cursor quick?

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

CSS:

```
td {
  /*animation*/
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
  transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

/*Element Animations*/
td:hover {
  transform: translateX(18px);
}
```

Comment: First of all always use *cross-browser CSS* when using *CSS3* properties and you've set `transition` for its normal view, add `transition` on `:hover` also, it'll work fine.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay: There is no need to set an extra `transition` property on `:hover`. The generic `td` selector applies when the element is hovered and when not hovered.

Comment: @Xufox It happens one in ten times. Not fully reproducable though. The transition works sometimes, sometimes not. It happens only if we move the cursor slowly to the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
td a {
  /*animation*/
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
  transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  margin-left:0px;

}

/*Element Animations*/
td a:hover {
  margin-left:18px;
}
```

Comment: It works, but the thing is that when on load the buttons would actually have a scale enlarge effect.